# Use library dependency inputs (Common properties vs. Linker Options)

Tags: c++, linker

I have an application using Caffe as a NN framework, and I am having issues running the code.

When my project is in the same solution as libcaffe, I can go to "Common Properties", and add libcaffe as a reference. Then set "`Link Library Dependencies`" and "`Use Library Dependency Inputs`" both to True, and my code works fine.

Now when I do the same in a stand-alone solution, and under `Linker->General` set those two values to "Yes", my code compiles, but does not work properly, it crashes when it reads the prototxt file, complaining that the layer names are unknown.

I read somewhere else that I should put `Linker->Optimization` to `/OPT:NOREF`, but that had no impact, my code is not working. How do I emulate the Common Properties->References in a stand-alone project, or what is happening here?

Comment: When you are using Common Properties and compile the solution - library and exe are compiled using same Platform/Configuration settings. Are you sure that when you set the reference to your library in the stand-alone project you are using same settings for exe and for library compiled separetely?

Comment: What settings do you mean? If its about Platform (x64) and Configuration (Debug), then yes, I use the same. I use the same compiler. No idea what causes this.